# localstack: aws cp fails to upload file to S3 bucket

Tags: amazon-s3, localstack

I launched a Docker container for the image `localstack/localstack:0.12.9.1`.
I opened the internal shell of this container by the command:

```
docker exec -it <container-name> sh
```

The next thing I wanted to do is to upload a file to S3 bucket.

I executed the command:

```
aws s3 cp /my-file.txt s3://my-bucket/. --region local --endpoint-url=http://local
stack:4566
```

and I got the error message:

> upload failed: ../../../my-file.txt to
> s3://my-bucket/. An error occurred (500) when calling
> the PutObject operation (reached max retries: 4): Internal Server
> Error

To be sure that this bucket exists, I executed the command:

```
aws s3api list-buckets --region local --endpoint-url=http://localstack:4566
```

and I got:

```
{
    "Buckets": [
        {
            "Name": "my-bucket",
            "CreationDate": "2021-05-14T14:23:03.000Z"
        }
    ],
    "Owner": {
        "DisplayName": "webfile",
        "ID": "bcaf1ffd86f41161ca5fb16fd081034f"
    } 
}
```

So the problem is not that the bucket is missing.

Do you know why I cannot upload file to S3?

Answer (score 1):

You need to create the folder inside bucket & copy the file inside the folder

```
aws s3api put-object --bucket my-bucket --key data/

aws s3 cp /my-file.txt s3://my-bucket/data/ --region local \
                             --endpoint-url=http://localstack:4566
```

Answer (score 0):

Did you also make sure the file `/my-file.txt` exists? since it should be located **inside** the container

There have been some changes/fixes with regards to s3. Did you also try with the `localstack/localstack:latest` image?

As a workaround you can open port `4566` and interact with it from outside the container, which should work. This also saves you from copying files into the container.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try checking the contents of the bucket? I did realize that the file was copied irrespective of the error shown.

```
aws --profile localstack --endpoint-url http://localhost:4566 s3 ls s3://my-local-bucket/
```